# Can the quote argument in write.table() only use double quotation marks?

Tags: r

In the `write.table()` function in R, is it possible to supply the `quote` argument with a character to use in place of the standard double quotes (`"`)?

e.g. an attempt to supply single quote `'` as argument:

```
  name sex age height
1   x1   F  18    162
2   x2   M  19    170
3   x3   M  21    178
4   x4   F  22    166
5   x5   F  23    165

write.table('test',data,sep=',',row.names=F,quote="\'")
```

which returns:

> Error in write.table("test", data, sep = ",", row.names = F, quote = "\'") : 
>     invalid 'quote' specification

Comment: As I said in a comment to an answer below, argument `quote` for `write.table` expects to be told wether or not to print the quotes in the resulting file (see `?write.table`). So this is not the correct argument to select between single and double quotes. That being said, I don't know which argument it would be (as argument `qmethod` doesn't seem appropriate either).

Comment: You could always work around this by preprocessing the character columns in your dataframe to add the quote characters you want, and then doing `write.table(..., quote=F)` since the quote marks are already there.  See  `?gsub` for one way to insert the quotes.

Comment: That's somewhat stupid. Why can't write.table have a character for quote, just like read.table?

Answer (score 4):

i get it .

1. `quote=T`,every column data will  be surrounded by double quotes.
2. `quote=F`,every column data will  not be surrounded by double quotes.
3. `quote=vector`,such as fellowing:

   > write.table(file='test',data,sep=',',row.names=F,quote=c(1,2))

the column 1,column 2 will be  surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: But this doesn't seem to answer your original question.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think Peng summarized the `write.table` argument `quote` where (s?)he realized that there's only `T`, `F` and `numeric` argument to be passed to this option.

Comment: I did not know that we can use `quote` for only selected columns of a dataframe. This answer saved my evening.